# My FileSplitter method does not write the data properly

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, split, stream

I'm trying to write a method that splits a file into little chunks,
I've tried to split an MP3 audio file of 6,67 mb and 2,55 minute length but if I merge the splitted parts (virtualy in a player) the merged file has a smaller length of 2:53 minute, this happens always, when the duration of the file to split is bigger (lets say a mp3 file of 30:00 minutes) the duration of the splitted files are more smaller (lets say 29:40 minutes).

Also, in a player, when one of the splitted parts of the track changes I can note that the sound "jumps" some milliseconds so is not properly "alligned/synchronized", seems that the splitted parts eats sound at the beginning.

The filesize of the splitted files are equals to the original file, but is obvious that all the data is not written properly.

So my method is missing some bytes at the end or at the start when reading or when writting the Bytes, I don't know where, How I can fix this?

***I've verified that this does not happens when I use various professional file splitters, is not a problem of the player, is a bug in my code.***

This is the method:

```
Public Sub SplitFile(ByVal InputFile As String,
                     ByVal ChunkSize As Long,
                     Optional ByVal ChunkName As String = Nothing,
                     Optional ByVal ChunkExt As String = Nothing)

    ' FileInfo instance of the input file.
    Dim fInfo As New IO.FileInfo(InputFile)

    ' The total amount of chunks to create.
    Dim ChunkCount As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(fInfo.Length / ChunkSize))

    ' The remaining bytes of the last chunk.
    Dim LastChunkSize As Long = fInfo.Length - (ChunkCount * ChunkSize)

    ' The Buffer to read the chunks.
    Dim ChunkBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(ChunkSize - 1L) {}

    ' The Buffer to read the last chunk.
    Dim LastChunkBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(LastChunkSize - 1L) {}

    ' A zero-filled string to enumerate the chunk files.
    Dim Zeros As String = String.Empty

    ' The given filename for each chunk.
    Dim ChunkFile As String = String.Empty

    ' The chunk file basename.
    ChunkName = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ChunkName),
                   IO.Path.Combine(fInfo.DirectoryName, IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fInfo.Name)),
                   IO.Path.Combine(fInfo.DirectoryName, ChunkName))

    ' The chunk file extension.
    ChunkExt = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ChunkExt),
                  fInfo.Extension.Substring(1I),
                  ChunkExt)

    ' Open the file to start reading bytes.
    Using InputStream As New IO.FileStream(fInfo.FullName, IO.FileMode.Open)

        Using BinaryReader As New IO.BinaryReader(InputStream)

            BinaryReader.BaseStream.Seek(0L, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)

            For ChunkIndex As Integer = 0I To ChunkCount

                Zeros = New String("0", CStr(ChunkCount).Length - CStr(ChunkIndex + 1).Length)
                ChunkFile = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", ChunkName, Zeros & CStr(ChunkIndex + 1I), ChunkExt)

                If ChunkIndex <> ChunkCount Then ' Read the ChunkSize bytes.
                    InputStream.Position = (ChunkSize * CLng(ChunkIndex))
                    BinaryReader.Read(ChunkBuffer, 0I, ChunkSize)

                Else ' Read the remaining bytes of the LastChunkSize.
                    InputStream.Position = (ChunkSize * ChunkIndex) + 1
                    BinaryReader.Read(LastChunkBuffer, 0I, LastChunkSize)

                End If ' ChunkIndex <> ChunkCount

                ' Create the chunk file to Write the bytes.
                Using OutputStream As New IO.FileStream(ChunkFile, IO.FileMode.Create)

                    Using BinaryWriter As New IO.BinaryWriter(OutputStream)

                        If ChunkIndex <> ChunkCount Then
                            BinaryWriter.Write(ChunkBuffer)
                        Else
                            BinaryWriter.Write(LastChunkBuffer)
                        End If

                        OutputStream.Flush()

                    End Using ' BinaryWriter

                End Using ' OutputStream

                ' Report the progress...
                ' RaiseEvent ProgressChanged(CDbl((100I / ChunkCount) * ChunkIndex))

            Next ChunkIndex

        End Using ' BinaryReader

    End Using ' InputStream

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hex editor to check both the splitted parts as well as the recombined file for error.

You can for example use the free version of Hex Editor Neo: http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor

First open your original file and go to the offset where the split is supposed to happen (make sure you don't mistake hex offset for a decimal offset. Image is for 500 MB Parts).

[image]

Then check and note the values before and after the offset. Everthing before is in Part1, everything after should be in Part2.

[image]

Open the two parts and compare the values at the end of Part1 and at the start of Part2 with the original file. They should match. If not, try the same with the professional tool as well.

If your code doesn't match, try mine (see your other question [Split a file into chunks larger than 2 GB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226492/split-a-file-into-chunks-larger-than-2-gb/) ). I just tested it myself and the split works fine. So there seems to be a problem with the recombination of the parts.

Comment: I really and stupidly thinked that an mp3 file doesn't necessarily needs the typical mp3 offsets to play its content, but I've used "mp3val" tool to fix mp3 problems (with splitted files, to repair the mp3 structure) and then I merged the files into 1 single file and all sound correctly now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot split media files at arbitrary points. Media files have internal structure which you will break. For example, you will split video and audio frames in half at random positions.

Apparently, your player can deal with broken files by skipped the broken parts. That's why content is not being played that you expected.

Comment: I understood it that his media player has some function to play a splitted file by internally recombining them. In that case your argument would not matter. If however he tries to just play each file, then you are completely correct.