# Split a file into chunks larger than 2 GB?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, split, stream

I'm trying to write a method that splits a file into fixed-size chunks, but I can't excceed the limit of **2147483590** (***Integer.MaxValue - 57***) per each chunk when creating the Buffer 'cause the `Byte` constructor only accepts an Integer.

I've read a suggestion in other S.O. answer that talked about creating little chunks (eg: 100 mb) and then append the chunks to get the real desired GB chunk-size, but I don't know whether that's the proper way or how to "append" the chunks.

Somone could help me?, here is what I've done:

```
Public Sub SplitFile(ByVal InputFile As String,
                     ByVal ChunkSize As Long,
                     Optional ByVal ChunkName As String = Nothing,
                     Optional ByVal ChunkExt As String = Nothing,
                     Optional ByVal Overwrite As Boolean = False)

    ' FileInfo instance of the input file.
    Dim fInfo As New IO.FileInfo(InputFile)

    ' The total amount of chunks to create.
    Dim ChunkCount As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(fInfo.Length / ChunkSize))

    ' The remaining bytes of the last chunk.
    Dim LastChunkSize As Long = fInfo.Length - (ChunkCount * ChunkSize)

    ' The Buffer to read the chunks.
    Dim ChunkBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(ChunkSize - 1L) {}

    ' The Buffer to read the last chunk.
    Dim LastChunkBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(LastChunkSize - 1L) {}

    ' A zero-filled string to enumerate the chunk files.
    Dim Zeros As String = String.Empty

    ' The given filename for each chunk.
    Dim ChunkFile As String = String.Empty

    ' The chunk file basename.
    ChunkName = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ChunkName),
                   IO.Path.Combine(fInfo.DirectoryName, IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fInfo.Name)),
                   IO.Path.Combine(fInfo.DirectoryName, ChunkName))

    ' The chunk file extension.
    ChunkExt = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ChunkExt),
                  fInfo.Extension.Substring(1I),
                  ChunkExt)

    ' If ChunkSize is bigger than filesize then...
    If ChunkSize >= fInfo.Length Then
        Throw New OverflowException("'ChunkSize' should be smaller than the Filesize.")
        Exit Sub

        ' ElseIf ChunkSize > 2147483590I Then ' (Integer.MaxValue - 57)
        '     Throw New OverflowException("'ChunkSize' limit exceeded.")
        '    Exit Sub

    End If ' ChunkSize <>...

    ' If not file-overwrite is allowed then...
    If Not Overwrite Then

        For ChunkIndex As Integer = 0I To (ChunkCount)

            Zeros = New String("0", CStr(ChunkCount).Length - CStr(ChunkIndex + 1).Length)

            ' If chunk file already exists then...
            If IO.File.Exists(String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", ChunkName, Zeros & CStr(ChunkIndex + 1I), ChunkExt)) Then

                Throw New IO.IOException(String.Format("File already exist: {0}", ChunkFile))
                Exit Sub

            End If ' IO.File.Exists

        Next ChunkIndex

    End If ' Overwrite

    ' Open the file to start reading bytes.
    Using InputStream As New IO.FileStream(fInfo.FullName, IO.FileMode.Open)

        Using BinaryReader As New IO.BinaryReader(InputStream)

            BinaryReader.BaseStream.Seek(0L, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)

            For ChunkIndex As Integer = 0I To ChunkCount

                Zeros = New String("0", CStr(ChunkCount).Length - CStr(ChunkIndex + 1).Length)
                ChunkFile = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", ChunkName, Zeros & CStr(ChunkIndex + 1I), ChunkExt)

                If ChunkIndex <> ChunkCount Then ' Read the ChunkSize bytes.
                    InputStream.Position = (ChunkSize * CLng(ChunkIndex))
                    BinaryReader.Read(ChunkBuffer, 0I, ChunkSize)

                Else ' Read the remaining bytes of the LastChunkSize.
                    InputStream.Position = (ChunkSize * ChunkIndex) + 1
                    BinaryReader.Read(LastChunkBuffer, 0I, LastChunkSize)

                End If ' ChunkIndex <> ChunkCount

                ' Create the chunk file to Write the bytes.
                Using OutputStream As New IO.FileStream(ChunkFile, IO.FileMode.Create)

                    Using BinaryWriter As New IO.BinaryWriter(OutputStream)

                        If ChunkIndex <> ChunkCount Then
                            BinaryWriter.Write(ChunkBuffer)
                        Else
                            BinaryWriter.Write(LastChunkBuffer)
                        End If

                        OutputStream.Flush()

                    End Using ' BinaryWriter

                End Using ' OutputStream

                ' Report the progress...
                ' RaiseEvent ProgressChanged(CDbl((100I / ChunkCount) * ChunkIndex))

            Next ChunkIndex

        End Using ' BinaryReader

    End Using ' InputStream

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't have to read the whole chucks in one go. Use the buffer to read small chucks (e.g. 1 MB each time) and write it to the current chuck. Do this until the file has the requested chuck size and then start the next file. Alternatively: .NET FrameWork 4.5 supports arrays larger than 2 GB (on 64 bit platforms!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have written in my comment you can just write data to the chunks until their size is large enough. Reading is done with a smaller buffer (I took some code parts from your question) in a loop while counting how many bytes have already be written.

```
' Open the file to start reading bytes.
Using InputStream As New IO.FileStream(fInfo.FullName, IO.FileMode.Open)
    Using BinaryReader As New IO.BinaryReader(InputStream)

        Dim OneMegabyte As Integer = 1024 * 1024 'Defines length of one MB
        'Account for cases where a chunksize smaller than one MegaByte is requested
        Dim BufferSize As Integer
        If ChunkSize < OneMegabyte Then
           BufferSize = CInt(ChunkSize)
        Else
           BufferSize = OneMegabyte
        End If

        Dim BytesWritten As Long = 0 'Counts the length of the current file
        Dim ChunkIndex As Integer = 0 'Keep track of the number of chunks
        While InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length

            ChunkFile = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", ChunkName, Zeros & CStr(ChunkIndex + 1I), ChunkExt) 'Define filename
            BytesWritten = 0 'Reset length counter

            ' Create the chunk file to Write the bytes.
            Using OutputStream As New IO.FileStream(ChunkFile, IO.FileMode.Create)
                Using BinaryWriter As New IO.BinaryWriter(OutputStream)

                    While BytesWritten < ChunkSize AndAlso InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length 'Read until you have reached the end of the input
                        Dim ReadBytes() As Byte = BinaryReader.ReadBytes(BufferSize) 'Read one megabyte
                        BinaryWriter.Write(ReadBytes) 'Write this megabyte
                        BytesWritten += ReadBytes.Count 'Increment size counter
                    End While
                    OutputStream.Flush()

                End Using ' BinaryWriter
            End Using ' OutputStream

            ChunkIndex += 1 'Increment file counter
        End While


    End Using ' BinaryReader
End Using ' InputStream
```

Comment: thankyou so much for the help, this solves the problem, but are you sure that the modifications that you've write are efficiently?, Splitting a file of 7 GB into chunks of 2 GB with winrar (no compression) takes 3:12 min while with this code takes 4:24 min, there is +60 secs of difference, could you verify whether all is ok? thankyou!

Comment: @ElektroStudios Experiment with the buffer size. I have put it at one megabyte but you can also make it scale with the file size to some extent. try 10 megabyte or 50 megabyte for example. Just beware that you might overshoot your single chunk sizes by some extent if your increase the buffersize. You may need to add some further code to avoid that (adjust the buffersize on the last read step).

Comment: On my harddisk the code takes roughly 17s per GB. So it would come out to around 2 minutes for 7 GB. I am not surprised that WinRAR is faster. They may have put in some more work over the last 10 years than the 10 minutes I did :-)

Answer (score 2):

Reconsider your approach. To split files you only need a small buffer. Read and write in 1MB chunks at the most. No need for more. With your approach you are buffering 2GB in RAM at once but there is no need to buffer the whole chunk. Just keep track of total bytes read and written to each file piece.

Technically you could make it work with a single byte buffer, though that would be inefficient.

If you really want to tune the performance, try overlapping the IO by using circular buffers or separate buffers with independent read and write threads, such that you can read and write in parallel. Once your read fills one buffer, you can let a write thread begin writing it while your read thread continues with another buffer. The idea is to eliminate the serial "lock step" from using a single buffer.